# Gradle 2.8 cargo war deployment compile method not found

Tags: gradle, cargo

le 'C:\Users\naresh.vatsal\workspace_spring_jan14\SpringMvcUsingGradle\build.gradle' line: 28

ent wrong:
m occurred evaluating root project 'SpringMvcUsingGradle'.
not find method compile() for arguments [org.springframework:spring-context:4.0.0.RELEASE] on org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.Default
cyHandler_Decorated@434c4af3.
   apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'eclipse'
    apply plugin: 'war'
    apply plugin: 'com.bmuschko.tomcat-base'
    apply plugin: 'com.bmuschko.cargo'
    ext.tomcatVersion = '7.0.67'
    ext.cargoVersion = '1.1.3'

```
sourceCompatibility = 1.7

buildscript
{

   repositories {
    maven {
      url "https://plugins.grdev.net/m2/"
       mavenCentral()
          }
}
  dependencies {
    classpath "com.bmuschko:gradle-tomcat-plugin:2.2.4"
     classpath 'com.bmuschko:gradle-cargo-plugin:2.2'
  }

 dependencies { 


    compile 'org.springframework:spring-context:4.0.0.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-webmvc:4.0.0.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.aspectj:aspectjrt:1.7.4'
    compile 'javax.inject:javax.inject:1'
   compile 'javax.servlet:jstl:1.2'
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.5'
    compile 'org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:1.7.5'
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:1.7.5'
    compile 'log4j:log4j:1.2.15'
     testCompile 'junit:junit:4.7' 
   }
}

cargo {
    containerId = 'tomcat7x'
    port = 8080

    local {
        homeDir = file('C:/mdi/soft/apache-tomcat-7.0.67')
        output = file('C:/mdi/soft/apache-tomcat-7.0.67/output.log')
    }
}
war {   
    version = '' `enter code here`
 }
```